# python with bpy to exe

Tags: python, blender, auto-py-to-exe, bpy

I've written a python script witch includes the bpy bibliothec.
The python script runs perfectly. But if I convert the script with auto-py-to-exe it dosen't start.
If I convert it as console based .exe, the console give me the following error:

```
bpy: couldn't find 'scripts/modules', blender probably won't start.
Freestyle: couldn't find 'scripts/freestyle/modules', Freestyle won't work properly.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ERROR (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v340\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:7337 pyrna_srna_ExternalType: failed to find 'bpy_types' module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ERROR (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v340\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:7337 pyrna_srna_ExternalType: failed to find 'bpy_types' module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ERROR (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v340\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:7337 pyrna_srna_ExternalType: failed to find 'bpy_types' module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ERROR (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v340\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:7337 pyrna_srna_ExternalType: failed to find 'bpy_types' module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ERROR (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v340\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:7337 pyrna_srna_ExternalType: failed to find 'bpy_types' module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ERROR (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v340\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:7337 pyrna_srna_ExternalType: failed to find 'bpy_types' module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ERROR (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v340\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:7337 pyrna_srna_ExternalType: failed to find 'bpy_types' module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ERROR (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v340\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:7337 pyrna_srna_ExternalType: failed to find 'bpy_types' module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ERROR (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v340\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:7337 pyrna_srna_ExternalType: failed to find 'bpy_types' module
```

I've installed it with auto-py-to-exe as "one directory" and "single file". But it makes no difference.

I have no Idea wehere to find the folder.
Something strange is also that if I understand correctly "blender-v340" the v440 is the version, but on my PC I have blender 3.5.
Could it be that the bpy package could not be executed from the exe file?

Edit:
I've made some changes at the auto-py-to-exe config:

Additional Files: added the missing file: bpy_types.py
Advanced:
--paths: give the path to the bpy modul directory (C:/Users/myUsername/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/3.5/scripts/modules)
--hidden-import: bpy

Now the exe file starts with the following Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grafisch_obl_fbx.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "bpy\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bpy'
```

But I can't find the _bpy file

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:
At auto-py-to-exe, i made some changes :

Advanced:
--collect-submodules: bpy
--collect-all: bpy